# Obtain a specific array member returnd by print_r in php

Tags: php, arrays

Follwing an example here on the site

```
<pre>
<?php
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
print_r ($a);
?>
</pre>
Output:-

<pre>
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
</pre>
```

How do I get only ONE element of the array into a PHP variable for further processing

Comment: You could try `foreach ( $a as $element )...`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the array index to access specific array element.

```
print_r($a['b']); // banana
print_r($a['c'][2]); // z
print_r($a['c'][0]); // x
```

Comment: Ermmm... this code doesn't even work! (The first line anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all of the elements using...

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
foreach ( $a as $element )  {
    echo print_r($element,true).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs.

```
apple
banana
Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => y
    [2] => z
)
```

Or accessing individual values...

```
$a = array ('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
echo $a['a'].PHP_EOL;    // apple
echo $a['c'][1].PHP_EOL; // y
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide index to array to get value at that index.
There are two type of array in PHP: Associative array and Indexed array.
Associative array has named index while Indexed array's index refer to array value starts from 0.
Associative array to get apple you have to provide named index a to array.

```
$apple = $a['a'];  //apple
```

and if you want to get x from array first you have to provide named index c to get c array and to get x from this

```
$x = $a['c'][0];   //x
```

Comment: I am trying to do a reverese gecoding and am getting the following return back. I am inserting below the top fragment of the result. How do I get from the the Short name of the city for example [2] - I tried all that I can think of and am getting errors.

Comment: Hi all, found the perfect answer here on the site. Thank you 
.$json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=2.993518,101.7874058&sensor=true');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
        
    foreach ($data['results'] as $item) {
        if( !empty( $item['address_components'] ) ){
            $longName = $item['address_components'][0]['long_name']; 
            $shortName = $item['address_components'][0]['short_name']; 
    
            print_r('Long Name:' . $longName);
            print_r(' Short Name:' . $shortName);
        }
    }